# How to draw a trigonometric pattern on HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, gradient, lines

I'm trying to draw a graphic pattern of lines from the black to the red depending on the Y value of a wave. To find out if I'm doing it right whit the approach, I started a test in JSFiddle:

[Test](http://jsfiddle.net/nWb6M/)

```
var j,k; 
k=255;

var green=150;
var blue=150;

var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');

for(j=0;j<k;j++)
            {

              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(j, 0);
              ctx.lineTo(j, 150);
              ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb("&j&", 0, 0)";
              ctx.stroke();  


            }
```

But the result is just a grey tone in all the lines, although the drawing method is inside a loop and the 'red' value is changing.

Comment: In JavaScript `&` is the binary AND operator, not the concatenation operator. http://jsfiddle.net/nWb6M/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting @Juhana's good suggestion into practice:

[image]

```
var j,k;
k=255;

var green=150;
var blue=150;

var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');

for(j=0;j<k;j++){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(j, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(j, 150);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb("+j+",0,0)";
    ctx.stroke();     
}
```